# How to highlight gmap marker on hover in primefaces

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, primefaces, google-maps-markers

I am using PrimeFaces to show a Gmap and a DataTable and a DataChart(Bar) to show information on a page. Now the rows in the datatable and bars in the datachart are related to the markers on the Gmap. I now want to implement the feature that when a bar is hovered or a row in the datatable is hovered it would highlight the related marker (basicly change the icon). I am having a hard time to figure this out with PrimeFaces. As all the examples i've found was pure Javascript, I couldn't find some PrimeFaces example, or have an idea to implement it with my current situation with PrimeFaces.

Does anybody know to implement this or a good source for information?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to retrieve the Gmap object through PrimeFaces. You need to assign a widgetvar to the gmap in the xhtml and then you can retrieve the gmap object in Javascript, like this:

```
PF('widgetvar').getMap()
```